# Not able to ping googl.com OR access any other docker from my Docker Container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-swarm, docker-network

My host machine is MAC and I have installed Docker on my machine.

1.) Have downloaded the mysql:5 image and started container from the same :-

```
docker container run -d -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -e MYSQL_DATABASE=learners --network bridge mysql:5
```

2.) Now I have logged into the Docker container, using the default bridge :-

```
(base) aditya@aditya-MAC PROJECTS % docker container exec -it c4 bash
root@c4abb2947a1f:/usr/local/bin# 
root@c4abb2947a1f:/usr/local/bin# 
root@c4abb2947a1f:/usr/local/bin# ping google.com
PING google.com (142.250.193.238) 56(84) bytes of data.

^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2090ms

root@c4abb2947a1f:/usr/local/bin# 
root@c4abb2947a1f:/usr/local/bin#
```

3.) On my host machine, here are networks I have :-

```
(base) aditya@aditya-MAC ~ % docker network ls           
NETWORK ID     NAME                         DRIVER    SCOPE
c0bcfcc8b9ac   aditya-network               bridge    local
197c1cbd4534   bridge                       bridge    local
e7b2d1393818   docker-hadoop_default        bridge    local
cf84498b715b   host                         host      local
69dd81905f0a   ksql-course-master_default   bridge    local
c0c5220ade8f   none                         null      local
(base) B0218162@APB-LTB0218162-MAC ~ %
```

Inside my docker, I am able to install any package like `apt-get install iputils-ping`.

Any help shall be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Update all Repos with command -> apt update
2. Install iputils with command -> apt install iputils-ping
   This worked for my system so I guess it should work for you too.